# How to decrease the time complexity of the following python code?

Tags: python, time-complexity, big-o

Looks like current memory complexity is O(1) and time complexity is O(k). How to keep the memory complexity at O(1) but decrease the time complexity to be O(log k)?

```
import math


# for loop includes k/2 (ie. if k/2 = 3.5, then i will go from [1, 3]. 1,2, and 3
def findPower(x,k):
    y =1
    m = math.trunc(k/2)
    if k == 0:
        return 1
    for i in range(1,m+1):
        y = y * x
    if(k%2 == 0):
        return y * y
    else:
        return y*y*x
```

Comment: Perhaps you should not name your function `pow` as it is a built-in function

Comment: Also what do you mean by O(n)? What's the n?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation_by_squaring, which it looked like you started doing but didn’t quite get all the way with…?

Answer (score 1):

You want the [fast power algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation_by_squaring), but you probably need a loop to implement it properly (instead of plain `if`s):

```
def fast_power(e, p):
    current = e
    result = 1
    while p > 0:
        if p % 2 == 1:
            result *= current
        p = p // 2
        current *= current
    return result
```